# Collecting simultaneous features or reducing tracking interval on location tracking in ArcGIS Collector?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector, tracklog

I encountered a problem in using collector for our data collection on the field. We are archaeologists doing prospection work and needing to create point features for found artefacts as well a streaming line features (with somewhere between 1-5 seconds tracking intervals) to know exactly where we walk in surveyed zones. We need this precision in our line features to calculate prospection intensity in said surveyed zones.

But, Collector seems to be unable to stream a line feature while you are taking points. The solution a fell upon was the use of the esri layer named « location tracking » which leaves a bread crumbs trail of points where you go with an interval of 30 seconds at the least.

Is there a way to modify the ESRI location tracking layer for it to use an interval under 5 seconds?

Or, by any chance, did anybody found a way to simply stream a classic line feature while collecting points?

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: you could update the web map spec with ago-assistant and see if that interval works. (remember to reload the map to pick up the changes)